# Why is "[][[]]" undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Our Beloved JavaScript can be very weird...

```
(![] + [])[+!+[] + +!+[]]                // 'l'
    + (![] + [])[+!+[]]                  // 'a'
    + ([![]] + [][[]])[+!+[] + [+[]]]    // 'i'
    + ([][[]] + [])[+!+[] + +!+[]]       // 'd'
 // Will output "laid"
```

The reason why JavaScript produces this output mainly depends on type casting of array and ability of + to cast 'things' into string. `![] // false` while `+[] // 0` my question is how did JavaScript successfully parse `[][[]]` to be undefined but reject `[][][]` as syntax error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]` means different things depending on the context

> ```
> [][[]]
> ```

The first `[]` creates a new array (array literal syntax).

Then `that_array[[]]` tries to read a property from that array (square bracket property accessor syntax).

The property name is `[]` (also array literal syntax), which being an array, gets converted to a string: `''`

Since there is no property named *an empty string*, it resolves to `undefined`.

In other words:

```
const array = [];
const propertyName = [].toString();
console.log(array[propertyName]);
```

> ```
> [][][]
> ```

This errors because while the first `[]` creates an array, the second `[]` tries to access a property from it but fails to include a value for the property name. It has `]` before the value, so the second `]` is unexpected. It never gets to the third `[]`.